# Why referencing undefined index won't give a warning?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Today, I've tested the following code:

```
<?php
    $a = array();
    $b = &$a[0]; // no warning???

    echo $b;
```

And I've noticed that it doesn't give a warning and simply references the undefined index.

In fact, setting the index after will allow your to reference it as if it existed before (????):

```
<?php
    $a = array();
    $b = &$a[0]; // no warning

    echo $b; // echoes nothing
    $a[0] = 1;
    echo $b; // echoes 1
```

This behaviour is consistent with PHP 4.4.9 all the way up to PHP 7.1.0.

Also, running `gettype($b)` will return  `NULL`.

---

However, without the reference:

```
<?php
    $a = array();
    $b = $a[0];

    echo $b;
```

I get the warning `Undefined offset: 0 in [...] on line 3`.

---

Why does this happen and what was the rational behind this?

Comment: That's also mentioned in the manual: ["Note: If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it will get created."](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Comment: @user2342558 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6bb4de4b0deef39c543593a75565882aa2b3cc4 Absolutely no change at all.

Comment: If you add `print_r($a);` to the end of your first example, you will see it's created element 0 (as mentioned above).

Comment: @mario That's a variable, not an array index

Comment: https://3v4l.org/rjGgi shows `0` is created when assigned as reference.

Comment: @NigelRen Good catch. That means that mario is right. But why this?

Comment: References simply create a zval storage, if there isn't one yet. And an array index in that regard is not much more than a local variable name. (Imagine a local variable: `${'0'}` - is mostly handled like `$arr[0]`.)

Comment: `$b = $a[0]` is an immediate, one-off assignment. Whatever happens to `$a[0]` later, `$b` is still what is was at the time of the assignment.  If `$a[0]` didn't exist at that time, then even if it is create later, that has no impact on `$b`. However, `$b = &$a[0]` and be thought of as a long-term or persistent assignment.  Changing `$a[0]` later changes `$b`.  So if you eventually assign something to `$a[0]`, `$b` now references that value.  So in the first case, there is no reason to create the undefined index.  In the second case, there is, because it has the potential to be meaningful.

Comment: That makes sense. But also ruins any `array_key_exists('0', $a)` checks, but does what you "expect" with `isset($a[0])`.

Comment: @PatrickQ That explains what may have been the reasoning.

Comment: Yup.  I certainly don't want to speak for those who actually designed the language, but that seems like a reasonable justification anyway.  Any question of "why was it done that way" can't really result in anything but speculation (unless one of the original architects happens to stop by).

Comment: You're right. Should I just delete the question, since it is kinda sort-of off-topic? (before anyone answers or something)

Comment: It's already been closed as a duplicate, so it can't be answered.  Your call as to whether or not you want to delete it.